# Apache virtual hosting url redirect from one domain to other domain without showing the url in the browser

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Apache virtual hosting url redirect from one domain to other domain without showing the url in the browser?

Comment: Full window size iframe.  Otherwise you could ajax-fetch a page from the other server but that is not a redirect.

Comment: No, I have need to redirect from abc.com/new to xyz.com without using ajax or iframe.

Comment: Browsers won't let you do that.  They don't want to let site xyz impersonate site abc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not redirect, that's called Reverse Proxy.

Example:

```
ProxyPass /url-path/ http://backend.example.com/url-path/
```

This will reverse proxy all requests to /url-path/whatever to the server backend specified

More information at:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do this with .htaccess if your sites are on different servers. Doing so would present big security hole, imagine if someone does this with a bank´s website.

However, if both are hosted on the same server try this on your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.domain1.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

If you own both domains you could accomplish this with domain name forwarding. Check the options in your registrar (maybe godaddy, or dns managers like cloudflare).